# Print Floyd triangle using multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to use two threads to print Floyd triangle(say one thread prints the number and the other prints the number in the line) as below.

[image: Floyd Triangle]

and so forth until the max number which is 15 in this case.

I tried following but it keeps on printing numbers one on each line

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    static volatile int lineNumber = 1;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        PrintFloyd print = new PrintFloyd();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new TaskHandler(print, 10), "T1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new TaskHandler(print, 10), "T2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class TaskHandler implements Runnable {

    static volatile int i = 1;
    static volatile int lineCount = 1;
    static volatile int lineNumber = 1;
    private int max;
    private PrintFloyd print;

    TaskHandler(PrintFloyd print2, int max) {
        this.print = print2;
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(">>>>" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        while(i < max){
            if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("T1")){
                print.printNumber(i);
            } else {
                print.breakLine();
            }           
        } 
    }
}

class PrintFloyd {

    boolean isBreakPoint = false;

    public void printNumber(int i) {

        synchronized(this){
            while (isBreakPoint == false) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                }
                System.out.print(i++ + " ");
                isBreakPoint = false;
                notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    public void breakLine(){
        synchronized(this){

            while (isBreakPoint == true) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            isBreakPoint = true;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to do it, or are wanting someone to write it for you? If the latter, that's not what StackOverflow is for. Please add the code you have attempted

Comment: It's also unclear why you need or want threads.

Comment: How do I edit question to add my code

Comment: @cricket_007 how do I edit my question ?

Comment: There's an edit link above the comment section here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code would help:

public class PrintPatternWith2Threads {

```
final static int MAX = 15;
final static String itemWriterName = "itemWriter";
final static String newLineWriterName = "newLineWriter";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Printer print = new Printer(MAX);

    Thread itemWriter = new Thread(new ItemWriter(print), itemWriterName);
    itemWriter.start();
    Thread newLineWriter = new Thread(new NewLineWriter(print), newLineWriterName);
    newLineWriter.start();
}
```

}

class ItemWriter implements Runnable {

```
private Printer print;

ItemWriter(Printer print) {
    this.print = print;
}

public void run() {
    while (print.current <= print.MAX) {
        print.printNumber();
    }
}
```

}

class NewLineWriter implements Runnable {

```
private Printer print;

NewLineWriter(Printer print) {
    this.print = print;
}

public void run() {
    while (print.current <= print.MAX) {
        print.printNewLine();
    }
}
```

}

class Printer {

```
public final int MAX;
public int current = 1;
public int itemsInALine = 1;

Printer(int max) {
    this.MAX = max;
}

public void printNumber() {
    synchronized(this) {
        for(int i = current; i < current + itemsInALine && i <= MAX; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        this.current = current + itemsInALine;
        itemsInALine++;
        notifyAll();
        try {
            if(this.current < MAX) {
                wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void printNewLine() {
    synchronized(this) {
        System.out.println();
        notifyAll();
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Surender this is exactly what I wanted. I was incorrectly calling wait() and notifyAll().